# ¿Cómo mostrar el cargo de un usuario por el número de rango?

Tags: php

Anduve intentado como mostrar el nombre de cargo de un usuario dependiendo del número de rango (columna rank, tabla users). Lo que quiero hacer es que sí el usuario tiene rank = 3, muestre el nombre de rango/cargo = inter, y así sucesivamente.

Código php:

```
$getstaff = $db->query("SELECT username,rank,look,motto,online,tarea FROM users WHERE rank >= 6 AND username != 'Illusionz' ORDER BY rank DESC");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($getstaff)) {
        $rank_user = $db->query("SELECT rank FROM users WHERE username");
        while($staff = $getstaff->fetch_assoc()) {
            switch($rank_user){
                case 3:
                $rankname = "Inter";
                break;
                case 4:
                $rankname = "Constructor(a)";
                break;
                case 5:
                $rankname = "Publicista";
                break;
                // Y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al número 14...
                default:
                // None
                break;
            }
            echo "<tr class='team'>
                    <td>
                    <img style='float:left' src='https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=".$staff['look']."&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&headonly=1&size=b&img_format=gif'>
                    <p style='padding: 5px 0'><a href='/users/".$staff['username']."' style='color:black;font-weight:bold;'>" . $staff['username'] . "</a><br>
                    <b>Departamento:</b> <i>" . $staff['tarea'] . "</i><br>
                    <b>Rango:</b> " . $rankname . "</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>";
        }
    }
```

Lo intente hacer con Switch() pero no sé si sea así o de otra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Podes crear una función PHP global que pase como parametro una ID del rank.

Ejemplo:

```
function getNameRank( $id ){
    $ranks = [
        1 => 'Bronce',
        2 => 'Plata',
        3 => 'Oro',
        4 => 'Diamante',
        // 5 => 'Otro'
        // ...
    ];

    return $ranks[ $id ] ?? 'rank_default';
}
```

Entonces en tu codigo sería:

```
$getstaff = $db->query("SELECT username,rank,look,motto,online,tarea FROM users WHERE rank >= 6 AND username != 'Illusionz' ORDER BY rank DESC");
if(mysqli_num_rows($getstaff)) {
    $rank_user = $db->query("SELECT rank FROM users WHERE username");
    while($staff = $getstaff->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rankname = getNameRank( $rank_user );
        echo "<tr class='team'>
        <td>
        <img style='float:left' src='https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=".$staff['look']."&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&headonly=1&size=b&img_format=gif'>
        <p style='padding: 5px 0'><a href='/users/".$staff['username']."' style='color:black;font-weight:bold;'>" . $staff['username'] . "</a><br>
        <b>Departamento:</b> <i>" . $staff['tarea'] . "</i><br>
        <b>Rango:</b> " . $rankname . "</p>
        </td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

---

Lo que no entiendo para que sirve esta consulta:

```
$rank_user = $db->query("SELECT rank FROM users WHERE username");
```

Si ya tienes tu consulta principal

```
$getstaff = $db->query("SELECT username,rank,look,motto,online,tarea FROM users WHERE rank >= 6 AND username != 'Illusionz' ORDER BY rank DESC");
```

Supongo que este seria el codigo correcto que deseas para mostrar los rangos de todos los usuarios obtenidos en la consulta:

```
$getstaff = $db->query("SELECT username,rank,look,motto,online,tarea FROM users WHERE rank >= 6 AND username != 'Illusionz' ORDER BY rank DESC");
if(mysqli_num_rows($getstaff)) {
    while($staff = $getstaff->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rankname = getNameRank( $staff['rank'] );
        echo "<tr class='team'>
        <td>
        <img style='float:left' src='https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=".$staff['look']."&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&headonly=1&size=b&img_format=gif'>
        <p style='padding: 5px 0'><a href='/users/".$staff['username']."' style='color:black;font-weight:bold;'>" . $staff['username'] . "</a><br>
        <b>Departamento:</b> <i>" . $staff['tarea'] . "</i><br>
        <b>Rango:</b> " . $rankname . "</p>
        </td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

Espero que te funcione :)